# How to create a faceting based on a column in second dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot

I want to create a graph that looks like:

[image]

Now I found the `cowplot` package which gave me a quite similar result.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
library(data.table)
library(ggridges)

d = data.table(iris)

a = ggplot(data = d, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=..count..)) +
  geom_density_line() + 
  geom_density_line(data = d[Species == "virginica"], aes(), fill="lightblue", color="darkblue") +
  theme_bw()

b = ggplot(data = d, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=..count..)) +
  geom_density_line() + 
  geom_density_line(data = d[Species == "versicolor"], aes(), fill="lightgreen", color="darkgreen") +
  theme_bw()

cowplot::plot_grid(a, b, labels=NULL)
```

The result looks like:

[image]

But, there are two points that bother me:

- It has a y-axix in both plots
- With my real data where I have up to 10 grids, the code becomes very long

I think it must be possible to use `facet_grid()`, `facet_wrap()` or something similar to achieve this. But I don't know how I can use a column from the dataframe of the second geometry to create these subsets without changing/losing the greyish background plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can feed one layer a version of the data without `Species`, so it calculates the whole thing as our background context, and another layer that includes `Species` to map that to `fill` and to the appropriate facet.

```
library(ggplot2); library(ggridges)
ggplot(data = iris, aes(Sepal.Length, ..count..)) +
  geom_density_line(data = subset(iris, select = -Species)) +
  geom_density_line(aes(fill = Species)) +
  facet_wrap(~Species)
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. Do you know if there is a way to prevent a behavior like with setosa (setosa-only is higher then full distribution)?

Comment: That's an artifact of the line smoothing. You can control the degree of smoothing using the `adjust` parameter, for instance `adjust = 2` to smooth it twice as much.